# How to know eclipse has web tools plaform

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, xml-editor

I am using the juno eclipse and i want to install the wtp for the xml editor. But i am confused whether web tool is already install or not.

2) which is best free plugin for the xml editing in the eclipse.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Open 'Help > About Eclipse' and click the 'Installation Details' button to see what you have installed.

Answer (score 1):

[Rinzo XML Editor](http://editorxml.sourceforge.net/download.html)

[OXygen XML Editor](http://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_editor/download_oxygenxml_editor.html)

[Altova XML Editor](http://www.altova.com/download.html)

[Exciting XML Editor](http://exciting-code.org/how-to-setup-eclipse-as-xml-editor)

Comment: Any idea about  what operation we can do with xml  in eclipse

Comment: XML stores data in plain text format, the storage is independent of your platform and your data can be exported, imported, or simply moved much easier. XML is also use for add plugin in eclipse.every plugin is built by XML fro integrate in eclipse.